# Upserting many documents in loop create multiple same documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Ok after mapReduce we got this situation, we have array of results which we want to upsert to DB. As i know upsert create new document if it doesn't exist, upsert criteria is

```
{ productId: ObjectId(), date: ISODate() }
```

For update i use

```
results.forEach(r => {
  await db.collection(collectionName).update(query, update, { upsert: true });
});
```

What i expected is for each productId and date is there only 1 document, but for every day there is few (let's say around 4) documents with same productId and date. It's like it few first iterations was executed at same time and at same time it's checked if this kind of document exist, if not it will create one.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Show where you create `update` and `query` variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upsert operation on MongoDB is [not atomic](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.update/#use-unique-indexes). Here you are not sequentializing your operations, as `forEach` doesnt wait for its callback to be completed when it is a promise.

You can use a normal for loop to sequentialize your operations (although I dont know what is the use of `r` variable here):

```
for (const r of results) {
    await db.collection(collectionName).update(query, update, { upsert: true });
}
```

This way operations would be done one after the other.

Comment: Thank you for reply, 'r' is just dataObject. Ok i will try this, although i was thinking if wrap everything in async await would help, but it didn't.

Comment: Lmk if it helps :) If you dont want to use a `for` loop there is always the `reduce` approach, you can find more info about it with a quick search

Comment: Hey man, it actually helps, thanks a lot :) I mean normal for loop,, reduce didn't go quite well for me atleast, or i don't know how you meant that.